# Postgres: Run some hard-coded SQLs then drop to interactive terminal

Tags: postgresql, psql

When you start interactive bash, it runs `.bashrc` first and then it gives you an interactive prompt. Very handy to setup bash in the right way.

I'm trying to do the same with Postgres client (psql). I want to set some [session configuration parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-set.html) before I run SQL statements interactively. Does psql let me do that?

The `-c` option and the `-f` option are the standard ways to run a pre-canned SQL statements, but the man page clearly states that those options are incompatible with the interactive mode.

Comment: Amazing enough `psql` has a `psqlrc` file. See here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) under the section "Files" at bottom pf page. Or search for `psqlrc` in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogy to .bashrc extend to the name as well.  You want `.psqlrc`